# Data Not Saved after click on submit button - MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

After click on the sumbit button and trying to debug the code i don't recieve any error or exception but the data not saved
I have a class called login ... need the user after click on login button save its data in the database
This is my Post Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Login model, string returnUrl)
    {
        Context db = new Context();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LoginName))
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("LoginName", "this field is required");
            return this.View(model);
        }
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var user = new Login { LoginName = model.LoginName, LoginPassword = model.LoginPassword };
                db.Logins.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            }


            else
                return View();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And this is my Login Class:

```
[Table("Login")]
public partial class Login
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string LoginPassword { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my DBContext:

```
public class LoginContext : DbContext 
{
    public LoginContext () : base("LoginContext ")
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

After return to the google link the data not saved.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and traced your code to see if its executing what you think it should?

Comment: Yes and work correctly and after that go to the database to check if the data saved not found anything had been saved

Comment: Is `ID` the primary key in the table and is it an identity (does the database generate ID's)?

Comment: Yes and if i check the table data in the code by debugging will found the id is incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of solution Finally i found that :

1. When adding the Code first code i had make the DBContext with the
   same name of the table name "Login".
2. Delete all of them then add the new code first "DBContext" and
   choose your DB.
3. Will find that the DBConext will added automatically and your tables also will added.
   That will work correctly.